# How to compare the current row with all the others in PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table like this

```
| id      | state          | updatedate  |
|:--------|:---------------|:------------|
| 1       | state_review   | 1668603529  |
| 1       | state_review   | 1668601821  |
| 1       | state_review_2 | 1668601821  |
| 2       | state_review   | 1668601709  |
| 2       | state_review   | 1668600822  |
| 2       | state_review_2 | 1668600747  |
| 3       | state_review   | 1668559849  |
| 3       | state_review_2 | 1668539849  |
| 3       | state_review   | 1668529849  |
| 3       | state_review_2 | 1661599849  |
| 3       | state_review   | 1668599849  |
```

I'm trying to find how to count first occurance of changed state for all ids based on provided values, i have two incoming states from(state_review) to(state_review_2)

in this particular case there would be only three changed states that are going
from state_review -> state_review_2

resulting table would look like this

```
| amount  |
|:--------|
| 3       |
```

I suspect window function might help with this but i'm not sure how to compare current state with all the others, states have to be ordered by id

Was trying to use this query, but that doesn't seem to work, instead of counting the latest unique transitions it counts all of them, if the first found transition doesn't match given states then skip the entire section for a certain id

```
SELECT
   COUNT(DISTINCT (
   CASE
      WHEN
         (
            q.state = 'state_review' 
            AND 'state_review' != 'state_review_2'
         )
      THEN
         ID 
   END
)) AS amount 
FROM
   (
      SELECT
         id,
         state
      FROM
         states_table
      WHERE
         updatedate >= 1668603529 
         AND updatedate <= 1671599849
         AND 
         (
            state = 'state_review' 
            OR state = 'state_review_2'
         )
      ORDER BY
         id, updatedate DESC
   )
   AS q
```

Comment: `AND 'state_review' != 'state_review_2'` - here you are comparing two string literals, this is always *true*.

Comment: Yeah this (AND 'state_review' != 'state_review_2') is excessive I'll remove it

Comment: If you `SELECT MIN(state), MAX(state) FROM states_table GROUP BY ... HAVING MIN(state) <> MAX(state)`, then use it in a sub query to calculate your expected 3, would that be OK? If not, why?

Comment: @Atmo This is a great suggestion but these aggregate functions would just return the shortest and longest states available for each id. I might have a case when for example under id - 1 I have 100 different states, basically, all I need to do is to find the latest(order by updatedate DESC) transition between two given states, state A -> state B

if first found transition doesn't match given states then skip the entire section for a certain id

Comment: Noted, I added an answer to do what I understood from your comment, hoping it is correct. `id = 3` is an annoying case in your question because it does not explicitly say if the chain of states was 1,2,1,2,1 (= same as the physical order of records on disk) or 1,1,1,2,2 or 2,2,1,1,1; try to redefine your table so that it can contain a primary key `(id, updatedate, <some additional column to make it unique, a serial maybe?>)`. Remember you cannot use how records are physically stored in any of your SQL queries because postgres and other DBMS provide no guarantee about it and may move records.

Comment: @Atmo this table actually is a replica of another table and it's not supposed to have its own serial id column, but I understand what you're saying, I'm relying on a specific order to build this chain of states which is simply ordering by updatedate DESC and grouping by id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Transitions between 2 predefined states can be obtained with a LAG function.
Example with `state_review` and `state_review_2`

```
SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT ID, LAG(State) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY updatedate) As FromState, State, updatedate
    FROM States_table
) T
WHERE FromState = 'state_review' AND state = 'state_review2'
```

You can do variations of the above:

- To avoid double-counting when an id transitioned from state S1 to state S2 several times, change the sub-query with `DISTINCT` and without `updatedate` like so: `SELECT DISTINCT ID, LAG(State) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY updatedate) As FromState, State`
- And of course, do `SELECT COUNT(*)` instead if all you want is the count.

Comment: Wow thank you so much, this actually works I was afraid that for example when I have all the states lined up after sorting by updatedate it would allow me to find unwanted transitions

like state_review then state_review_2 then state_review_3

i would put in FromState = 'state_review' AND state = 'state_review3' and expecting it would find something, skipping transition between state_review and state_review2 but it didn't which is what i wanted, thanks again :)